# Delete a row in databse if has a code that has been present for 15 min

Tags: codeigniter

On my model I am trying to make a function so when I reload my page it will check if any rows have a code set and check the date_modified time 2017-02-16 13:53:18 and if has been present for more than 15min will remove row.

> **Question:** On each post The column "code" if has any value then will check the date and time if has been there longer 15 min with code value still present then will remove row.

I have tried this below but when I reload page it does not remove any row.

Model Function

```
public function clear_unconfirmed_post() {
    $this->db->where('code is NOT NULL', NULL, FALSE);
    $this->db->where('date_modified < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE))', NULL, FALSE);
    $this->db->delete($this->db->dbprefix . 'post');
}
```

Controller Construct Area

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('catalog/forum/newthread_model');
    $this->newthread_model->clear_unconfirmed_post();
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your `date_modified` field is `datetime` and you are comparing it with a integer (that is was `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function returns). I would advise as a general rule of thumb, using UNIX timestamp (i.e - `INT` fields) directly when storing dates, for easier comparisons and not being affected by timezones.

Comment: @RonDadon thank you for pointing that out. I will change it and see if it works.

Comment: Great, thank you :) posted as an answer with more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `date_modified` field is of type `DATETIME` and you are comparing it with a `integer` (that is was [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function returns).

I would advise *as a general rule of thumb*, using UNIX timestamp (i.e - `INT` fields) directly when storing date-time values, for easier comparisons and for not being affected by timezones, as UNIX timestamps are in UTC (+0), so they can be used very easily for timezones conversions.

So when storing a value in the `date_modified` field, instead of storing a value like this (the example shows variable assignment in PHP):

```
$date_modified = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // 2017-02-07 10:18:00 in UTC+2 timezone
```

You will store it like this:

```
$date_modified = time(); // 1486455515 which equals to 2017-02-07 08:18:00 in UTC
```

Answer (score 0):

In the mysql query now() will take the server time so it is better to pass it using php

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$time = strtotime($date);
$time = $time - (15 * 60);
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);
```

in model

```
 $this->db->where('date_modified <' $date);
```